# How to increase performance of building Substrate by "cargo build --release" command

Tags: substrate-node-template, build, performance

I using `Substrate-template-node` to build pallet and my laptop have Core-i7 chip, but the time to build is range from 9-12 minutes. So, when I change code and have to wait to build and run.

So, my question is Is there anyway to build faster?

Comment: If you do `cargo build --profile production` then you will appreciate how much faster `cargo build --release` is.

Comment: `SKIP_WASM_BUILD` can be used to only build the code in native mode. Which OS are you using? Different linkers can help a bit. An AMD 5950x can help a lot.

Comment: Remember there's also `cargo check` that can be done first which is a lot faster, and faster still if you're in the directory of the pallet as it has less to build.

Comment: @Squirrel I encountered this error when run `cargo build --profile production` :`error: profile 'production' is not defined`

Comment: why are you building with release anyway?

Comment: @BryanChen sorry, I dont understand your question?

Comment: If you run a chain in debug mode at the moment it doesn’t run fast enough for the blocks to complete successfully. Production profile enables fat lto, and is defined on polkadot and cumulus.

Comment: @Squirrel the solution will be fix it so that debug build works. Not using release build for debug build. Debug build certainly works for us so it is something can be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some answers recommend to build with `--release` or with a production profile. But this misses the point of the original question. If you do this the build will actually take longer due to a number of additional optimizations that are applied!

You should consider the difference between using `cargo build` and `cargo check`:

> This will essentially compile the packages without performing the final step of code generation, which is faster than running cargo build.

(from the [`cargo-check`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-check.html) docs)

So if you e.g. just want to check for compiler errors `cargo check` is already sufficient.

If you're really in need for faster binary builds then having a beefy remote machine on which you execute the build via [`cargo-remote`](https://github.com/sgeisler/cargo-remote) can be an option. There are also reports that using a local [`sccache`](https://github.com/mozilla/sccache) installation + setting the environment variable `RUSTC_WRAPPER="sccache"` speeds this process up due to the additional caching done through `sccache`.

Comment: marked as answer for detail answer.thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a pallet testing just the pallet instead of building the entire thing is better. Just run `cargo check -p your_pallet_name`.

Comment: hum, I need to build and run test.

Comment: `cargo test -p your_pallet_name` would run just your pallets tests.

Answer (score 0):

`rustflags = [ "-Zthreads=8" ]` will help if you're on nightly. As far as I know this is not on by default so stick it in your `~/.cargo/config` - Had it in there for months and not seen a down side.