# How to speed up compilation

Tags: substrate-contracts-node

I was wondering how to speed up the substrate build?
it takes me about half an hour to get the binaries (without cache)
any leads are welcome other than changing my laptop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `cargo remote` with a cloud server to significantly reduce the build time (few minutes depending on the server power).

there is a detailed post about this topic :
https://www.chevdor.com/post/2019/12/23/cargo-remote/

another post described the process using Google cloud :
https://medium.com/commonwealth-labs/build-substrate-in-few-minutes-with-fraction-costs-26fce6aa5066

Answer (score 2):

I've written another answer on the general topic [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/how-to-increase-performance-of-building-substrate-by-cargo-build-release-com/1444#1444), this might already help you further.

But since you specifically tagged for `substrate-contracts-node`: There are binary releases available at [the GitHub releases page](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases), this might already solve your problem if you don't want to do more modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give [Fleet](https://github.com/dimensionhq/fleet) a try.

Comment: I was using Fleet on Debian machine but did not see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be the most practical immediate solution, highly recommend getting Apple M1. Builds drastically reduced to a few minutes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).